# Can I insert Arrays as params in a Query within Stored Procedures?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Giveb the following query within an stored procedure

```
'SELECT * FROM Players p where p.id IN("somevalue","someothervalue")
```

I want to parametrize this query and use the query object within the stored procedures.

```
var filterQuery = 
{     
    'query' : 'SELECT * FROM Players p where p.id IN(@ids)',
    'parameters' : [{'name':'@ids', 'value':["somevalue","someothervalue"]}]
}
```

is the above possible?

Also extra Karma points for pointers to documentation about the query object.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can equivalently write the IN query via ARRAY_CONTAINS, which can be parameterized, like shown below:

```
var filterQuery = 
{     
    'query' : 'SELECT * FROM Players p where ARRAY_CONTAINS(@ids, c.id)',
    'parameters' : [{'name':'@ids', 'value':["somevalue","someothervalue"]}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above is possible in stored procedure.This should work:

```
function executeQuery(query, parameters) {
    console.log(query);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(parameters));
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        {
            query: query,
            parameters: parameters
        },
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else return the feed
            if (!feed || !feed.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody('no docs found');
            }
            else {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                var body = feed;
                response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
            }
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

**Note**: you might need to change your query to `SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(@ids,c.id)` to make it work with arrays

You can do any basic JS operations in stored procedure.Cosmosdb also provides a bunch of methods which you can refer here:
https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/index.html

They also have an alternative syntax for querying which is JS friendly.You can refer the cheatsheet here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/javascript-query-api#sql-to-javascript-cheat-sheet